# ASP.NET Core Web API: make all requests wait for results of async method called by the first request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

My web API consumes `POST`-requests mostly. There are `BigQuery` tables being appended with data containing in these requests. **The first request updates the table schema** in a way that allows other requests not spend their time doing it again (if incoming data aren't going to change the schema).

The thing is, all following requests know that there's no need in changing the schema, so they **invoke streaming data** in the tables **before these tables comply** the data.

Here's a simplyfied example. Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostData([FromBody] List<Dto> dtos)
{
    try
    {
        await _dataSender.SendAsync(_mapper.Map<List<Data>>(dtos));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
}
```

DataSender:

```
public async Task SendAsync(List<Data> data)
{
    if (_schemaManager.IsUpdateNeeded(data))
    {
       _bigQuery.UpdateTableSchemaAsync(_schemaManager.GetSchema(data));
    }
    // prepare data and do some related stuff
    await _bigQuery.WriteEventAsync(preparedData);
}
```

I used to `await _bigQuery.UpdateTableSchemaAsync(_schemaManager.GetSchema(data));`, but this way another calls of `SendAsync` know nothing about **the task that is called inside of this method**. So now I save this task in a private `Dictionary` inside of `UpdateTableSchemaAsync`:

```
_updateSchemaJobsByTable[tableName] = updateQueryJob.PollUntilCompletedAsync();
```

This way I hope to make `WriteEventAsync` wait for this task to complete **no matter what request is calling this method**:

```
public async Task WriteEventAsync(List<PreparedData> data)
{
    // ...
    Task task;
    while (!_updateSchemaJobsByTable.TryGetValue(tableName, out task))
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
    await task;
    // write the data
}
```

This works until concurrent request number to the API reaches ~800. After that the execution of `WriteEventAsync` **never comes to what's after `await`**, and I get an exception saying that **update schema task is cancelled**.
I wonder if it is related to the solution I came up with (I bet it is, though) and ask for pointing out all the mistakes. I feel like I've made a lot :)

Comment: `Dictionary` isn't threadsafe.

Comment: Dealing with 800 concurrent write request is no small feat. Isn't your storage solution overwhelmed?